# fast multiplications

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization

When I am going to compute the following series `1+x+x^2+x^3+...`, I would prefer to do like this: `(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)...` (which is like some sort of repeated squaring) so that the number of multiplications can be significantly reduced.

Now I want to compute the series `1+x/1!+(x^2)/2!+(x^3)/3!+...`, how can I use the similar techniques to improve the number of multiplications?

Any suggestions are warmly welcome!

Comment: @jrd1 - Why would it matter?

Comment: Hint: Keep a temporary variable that stores `x^k/k!`. Then at each iteration, multiply it by `x` and divide it by `k`.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate 1+x^n ... as (1+x)(1+x^2) no matter how much you want.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Yeah, I was wondering about that... The OP is probably (incorrectly) remembering some varient of Horner's Method.

Comment: Also a lookuptable of the reciprocals of (n!) could come handy (and it would improve also accuracy). You won't probably need more than 20 of those anyway.

Comment: Regarding first series, note that `1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n` = `(1-x^(n+1))/(1-x)`

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen - The infinite series 1+x+x^2+... is, in fact, equal to (1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^(2^i))... The radius of convergence is |x| < 1.

Comment: @TedHopp: and it is easy to prove - just multiply `(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^(2^i))...` by `(1-x)` - it will be obviously reduced to `1` when `|x| < 1`

Comment: I'll stand corrected. (1+x)(1-x) == (1-x^2), which multiplied by (1+x^2) == (1-x^4) and so on -- pretty much like in my answer below. In practice however, the explicit formula using a division could be much faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method of optimization you refer, is probably Horner's method:

```
a + bx +cx^2 +dx^3 = ((c+dx)x + b)x + a
```

The alternating series A*(1-x)(1+x^2)(1-x^4)(1+x^8) ... OTOH is useful in calculating approximation for division of A/(1+x), where x is small.

The Taylor series `sigma x^n/n!` for exp(x) converges quite badly; other approximations are better suited to get accurate values; if there's a trick to make it with less multiplications, it is to iterate with a temporary value:

```
  sum=1; temp=x; k=1; 
  // The sum after first iteration is (1+x) or 1+x^1/1!
  for (i=1;i<=N;i++) { sum=sum+temp; k=k*(i+1); temp = temp * x / k; }
  // or
  prod=1.0; for (i=N;i>0;i--) prod = prod * x/(double)i + 1.0;
```

Multiplying the factorial should increase accuracy a bit -- in real life situation it's may be advisable to either combine `temp=temp*x/(i+1)` in order to be able to iterate much further, or to use a lookup table for the constant a_n / n!, as one typically needs just a few terms. (4 or 5 terms for sin/cos).

As it turned out, Horner's rule didn't have much role in the *transformation* of the geometric series `Sigma x^n` to product form. To calculate exponential, other powerful techniques have to be applied -- typically range reduction and rational (Pade), polynomial (chebyshev) approximations and such.

Comment: If we iterate Saury's formula `x/1 ( 1+ x/2 (1 + x/3 * (1 + x/4(.....))))`, would it be faster than your iterations ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Believe it or not, there are even faster ways than that. (methods that involve only a single division) But they are complicated, so I won't go into them. These advanced methods are the ones that are used to evaluate such series to extremely high precision (millions of terms to millions of digits) - which I assume is well beyond the scope of your project.

Comment: @Mysticial, could u kindly give a reference for such methods?

Comment: @Aki, I was wondering if Aksi's method get the Horn's trick utilized.

Comment: I think the asymptotic behaviours are the same: one division, one multiplication and one addition per iteration. And as there's an error in my formula, they are also behaviourally the same. Saury's missing `1+` from the beginning... And I'll have to edit my answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith If you insist, [here it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_splitting). But I warn you though, it is not easy to grasp. Furthermore, it is completely overkill for what you are trying to accomplish and can be drastically simplified for primitive data-types. I do *not* recommend it. It is like killing a cockroach with a 50 megaton thermonuclear warhead.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, what's the iterative form of Saury's formula?

Answer (score 1):

On your approach for the first series don't you think that using 1 + x(1+ x( 1+ x( 1+x)....)) would be a better approach. Similar approach can be applied for the second series. So 1 + x/1 *( 1+ x/2* (1 + x/3 * (1 + x/4(.....))))

Comment: How to apply the similar approach to the second series? That's my question.

Comment: Thanks @AkiSuihkonen for correcting me. I guess the edited one should work

Comment: I made that in 2nd edit earlier but did not got it saved sadly I guess :(. I have made edit again

Answer (score 1):

Converting comment to an answer:

Note that for first series, there is exact equivalence:

```
1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n = (1-x^(n+1))/(1-x)
```

Using it, you can compute it much, much faster.

Second one is convergence series for `e^x`, you might want to use standard math library functions `pow(e, x)` or `exp(x)` instead.

Comment: Wasn't OP's original series infinite?

Comment: Can you also quote the region of convergence? (In the first series |x| < 1, I suppose?

Comment: It's interesting to note that a naive implementation of `x^(n+1)` is still gonna require order `O(n)` multiplications. So you'd need to use the binary exponentiation algorithm.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen That's correct. For the second series, it *always* converges. But if `x` is large and negative, it becomes numerically unstable and there will be significant round-off error.

Comment: assume we can not use `exp()` function, and `0<x<1` for both series.

Comment: then @Mysticial advice regarding keeping current `x^n/k!` is probably the best. For first series, formula I suggested will win if using binary exponentiation